# Searching in sharepoint url

Tags: list, search

We have a SharePoint Online List that contains alot of urls to different documents on other SharePoint sites.
Is it possible to perform a search within that list that also searches in the documents where the url is linked to?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

Searching the list would only return the contents of the list e.g. the list metadata.

You could create a SharePoint page with [PnP Modern Search](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/) web parts and configure those web parts to return results from the sites containing the documents. Alternatively, if the sites are part of a hub site, then searching from that hub site would return the documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We will look in to that

Comment: Glad to help, remember to upvote/mark as the answer where appropriate if the question is answered to help inform the community.

Comment: "We have a SharePoint Online List that contains alot of urls to different documents on other SharePoint sites" - if this list in fact is an Index of other documents i.e. if you need your users staying on this site being able to search throug documents on other 
 sites - based on content, metadata etc also being able - to refine list of docs (e.g. by author, date, subject etc. ) 
PnP Search Webpart can be a solution. With proper config - you'd no need this list.